# unable to view data in data frame after removing NA values

Tags: r, date, na

I've two data frames in time and out time with around 240 columns and 4100 rows. 
There are lots of NA values in both the data frames which I need to remove and then subtract in time from out time.
I gave this command below to remove all the NA values
out_time1 <- na.omit(out_time)

Then when I give view(out_time) I get only head rows in my data frame. I am unable to view any data now. Why is it so? The same thing happens with in_time data frame as well.

1. Please help me in removing the NA values from these two data frames.

Regards,

Pavan.

Comment: `na.omit` will remove all rows that have `NA` in ANY column. Maybe there are no rows without `NA`. Maybe you want to remove `NA`s from a specific column only?

Comment: Are you working with date data and that's why you included the date tag? I don't think there is anything specific about dates in this case, they work just like other variables.

Comment: If your question has been answered can you mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that at least 1 column for every row has an NA, resulting in no data being returned. If you use `complete.cases()` you can see a row-wise NA check.

```
# Example Data
test <- diag(rep(NA,4))
test[1,1] <- 0
test
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    0   NA    0    0
#[3,]    0    0   NA    0
#[4,]    0    0    0   NA

complete.cases(test)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

if `sum(complete.cases(test))` does not equal at least 1, then you have no rows that are absent of NA data. You should thoroughly investigate your data for NAs.

You can make use of `table(is.na(test))` or `rowSums(is.na(test))` or `colSums(is.na(test))`

Comment: Also worth considering if it makes sense to use rm.na=TRUE on an as needed basis when working with specific variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that `View(out_time)` gives you the column headers and nothing else, it is because there are no data present in the data frame, leaving just the headings.

Basically, you deleted everything in the data frame because `na.omit(out_time)` removes any rows that have a single `NA` present.